# show dynamic value as the first element in the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on angularjs forEach loop.I am showing dropdown list with dynamic values.
I am getting `$scope.showCurrentProgram` dynamically which i wanted to show as the first element selected in the list when the page is loaded and remove the same element from the dropdown list($scope.programs).

Sample js code:

```
app.controller("BaseController", function($scope) { 
  $scope.title = "Angular.ForEach"; 
  $scope.showCurrentProgram="Oracle";//dynamically showCurrentProgram value is updated which need to be shown on the dropdown list as the selected item and remove that element from the list
     $scope.programs = ["ALL","C","C++","java","SAP","Oracle",".net","ABAP"];
});
```

html code:

```
  <select name="selectedPrograms" ng-model="selectedProgram" ng-options="x for x in programs" ng-change="updatePrograms()"></select>
```

expected output:
Display Oracle as the first element in the list on page load.
$scope.showCurrentProgram loads some value dynamically at runtime which need to be shown as the selected element(first element) in the dropdown list.

Answer (score -1):

Just set the **`$scope.selectedProgram`** to the value you want to bind and set it as the ng-model in the template.

**Demo**

```js
var app = angular.module('BaseApp',[]);
app.controller("BaseController", function($scope) { 
  $scope.title = "Angular.ForEach"; 
  $scope.selectedProgram="Oracle"; 
     $scope.programs = ["ALL","C","C++","java","SAP","Oracle",".net","ABAP"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="BaseApp" ng-controller="BaseController">
<select name="selectedPrograms" ng-model="selectedProgram" ng-options="x for x in programs" ng-change="updatePrograms()"></select>
</body>
```